# Is it possible to delete 15 ad groups in one second without PS?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, domain-controller

I deleted 2 user accounts in AD running on Windows 2016 (pdc), time stamp is around 1:05:00 pm, then the users report cannot access the share drive on a domain member file server.

Then I found in event log shows I deleted over 10 groups in ONE SECOND at 15:05:16, I haven't done such things and never use script.

1. I was test GPO (add and delete) at that time, is this caused such error ?
2. Apart from operation error, any other possibilities will cause over 10 groups deleted in 1 second which looks not like a human's action?
3. What reason should use in incident report?

I Googled, only use PS may cause such action, is this true? Maybe a bug?

Comment: How can we answer what happened without having access to logs?

Comment: Incident report: Im not sure why my rights have been misused. There is no way I can explain what happened. And I'm not sure why I have so many rights, that I can do this.' aslong as you dont overcome with [ask] its at current sate offtopic - and `yes it is possible to wipe an entire AD within milliseconds.`

Answer (score 1):

- NO, If you used the default "User and computers" interface? and deleted them one at the time
- YES, if you accidentally did a multi-select and have forgotten you had the groups selected

If the eventlog show you deleted the groups, there is little left for debate :)
You could include that the deletions "were unintended" and it led to "unanticipated problems"

Comment: So much effort into this post and its responses - a simple "I goofed" in the incident report with a 30 second "Restore-ADObject" is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a system glitch or even an undetected script running amok. In your incident report, maybe chalk it up to an unidentified system anomaly while testing GPOs. Definitely keep digging, maybe even check with the Microsoft community or support

Comment: Highly unlikely.